# Folder sizes and disk usage do not add up

Tags: finder, file, disk-space

I needed to transfer the contents of a drive to a new drive and ran into an issue copying my Dropbox folder. I tried to copy this folder using `rsync`, but I found that it took 20 seconds between each file transfer, which is an issue due to this drive having many small files.

I checked the folder size and it shows "12,858,279,864 bytes (61.5 MB on disk) for 217,350 items". How is it possible that this folder is using 61.5mb when it's total size is over 12GB. I checked the drive and it is showing only 1.45GB used, which is confusing since the drive only contains this folder and an exact copy of it.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: Can you issue the command `du -h /old/drive/folder` and `du -h /new/drive/folder` and post the last line of each to the question with an [edit]?

Comment: Is your Dropbox located at ~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox? If so, it is using "files on demand". With this, some file content may be in the Dropbox cloud with stubs on your Mac.